# Intellij code inspection maven plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, continuous-integration, maven-plugin

It's actully two questions in one:
1. Is IntelliJ code analyzer open source?
2. Is there a maven plugin to run it during the build?

Comment: If it is in Community version, then yes.

Comment: The code for a lot of inspections (e.g. for Java) are open sourced: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community. I'm not aware of the maven plugin that runs them. But you can run inspections from command line https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-inspections-offline.html

Answer (score -1):

I once asked the folks at IntelliJ if there was a way to do this, and they sent me an email explaining how. I don't have it anymore (I wasn't allowed to try it at work), but I know it can be done. I hope to post more later.

Comment: This not really an answer. If you have more information for us, then I will give you an upvote.